# c# unity www.text has error text not in www.error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

while i'm using WWW in Unity3D(c#), i found ridiculous result.

www.text has error text not in www.error. so i can't check whether error occured.

```
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (www.error)) {
                //handling error
                //but www.error is null
            }else{
                //print www.text
                Debug.Log(www.text);
            }
```

[print console]

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
            <html><head>
            <title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
            </head><body>
            <h1>Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
            <p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
            request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
            problems. Please try again later.</p>
            <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
            error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
            </body></html>
```

does anybody has this experience? please help me..

Comment: Insert a breakpoint at line if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (www.error)) obviously www.
     error is not null.Maybe it only contains whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

Your check with `IsNullOrEmpty` looks fine to me. Never seen any whitespace there, only empty string or `null`.

Check what HTTP code is returned by the server. Stating in HTML that this is the error code not necessarily mean that the protocol error is the same. Some proxies or broken setups can cause this.

Get [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) and check the error code:

```
curl -v http://example.com/lipsum
```

and look for:

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

or simmilar.